# Protect subdirectory with .htaccess and .htpasswd

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have a directory `memories` and there is a subdirectory in it `/memories/application/controllers/admin`.
I want to protect `admin` directory using `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd`.

This is my `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    AuthUserFile /var/www/memories/application/controllers/admin/.htpasswd
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "memories with mom"
    Require admin
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>

# Various security things
ServerSignature off
php_value expose_php Off
php_value  session.cookie_httponly On
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /404.php
```

But it is protecting the whole parent directory, whereas I only want the subdirectory `admin` to be protected. My `.htpasswd` is also in admin folder.

Comment: Put a .htaccess file in the folder `/var/www/memories/application/controllers/admin/` and add there your configuration `RewriteEngine On
AuthUserFile /var/www/memories/application/controllers/admin/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "memories with mom"`...

Comment: this is Not working for me

Comment: what exactly happen? What do you mean by "not working"? is still the complete parent directory locked?

Comment: Nothing is locked...when i go to admin ,it does not ask for authentication

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the subdirectory admin protected by the `.htpasswd` file then only put the auth specific htaccess code in that subdirectory and not the `.htaccess` for the whole site.

`/var/www/memories/application/controllers/admin/.htaccess` should only be

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/memories/application/controllers/admin/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "memories with mom"
Require admin
```

and remove the above code from your main .htaccess